# Robot-Relative Movement

Tags: sphero-api, sphero

By default, Sphero movement commands are user-relative, set by the initial orientation calibration (blue tail light).

I have added FPV hardware to one of my Spheros and wish to issue robot-relative movement commands. Seems like this should actually be easier, but from what I can see, I may have to instead issue direct motor control commands, defeating stabilization and other great features.

Is there a way of changing modes or a command set that offers simple robot-relative navigation?